# How to change string which comes from breadcrumbs?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I have used custom breadcrumbs module.

Now one of my title of blog has single quote or double quotes, which is having problems.

So, in titles i have added

> [node:title]

so output of the title whose having quotes are like

```
Home > blog > Politics > No Democracy but many other &#039;o-cracies&#039;
```

and i have added hook which will show the output is like this..

```
function myowntheme_breadcrumb($variables) {
    $sep = ' &gt; ';
  if (count($variables['breadcrumb']) > -1) {
    return implode($sep, $variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
  else {
    return t("Home");
  }
}
```

How to remove that hash tag values and show on simple version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nodes contain apostrophe in their title. Node titles will be passed through `check_plain()` function and it uses `htmlspecialchars()` function to convert the quotes to HTML entities.

You may try by decoding them back

```
function myowntheme_breadcrumb($variables) {
    $sep = ' &gt; ';
  if (count($variables['breadcrumb']) > -1) {
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(implode($sep, $variables['breadcrumb']),ENT_QUOTES);
  }
  else {
    return t("Home");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you...
Many time, you have to think simple to do simple thing.. :)